# Get accurate file creation date from Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, wmic

I'm trying to get accurate (with ms resolution) creation date of a file using python.

The way to get accurate creation date on Window is to use [wmic](https://superuser.com/questions/937380/get-creation-time-of-file-in-milliseconds).
So I've prepared a simple shell command to read the creation date:

```
wmic datafile where name="C:\\Users\\Public\\test.txt" get creationdate | findstr /brc:[0-9]
```

that runs ok crom a CMD shell on Win10 (if the file is there)
I then tried to run the same command from python using subprocess:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT, CalledProcessError
cmd = 'wmic datafile where name="C:\\Users\\Public\\test.txt" get creationdate | findstr /brc:[0-9]'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print( "program output:", out)


try:
    o = check_output(cmd, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
    returncode = 0
except CalledProcessError as ex:
    o = ex.output
    returncode = ex.returncode
    if returncode != 1: # some other error happened
        raise
finally:
    print(o)
```

But I got the same error message:

> Node - username
> ERROR:
> Description = Invalid query

do you have any suggestion on how to get more info on the error of fix it?

Comment: Just a guess, but python converts the call to `cmd.exe /c your-command-here` and I suppose that could mess with the quotes. I don't have windows up to test, but perhaps making `"` into `""` may help.

Comment: You can do wmi calls programatically via the `win32` api as outlined by Tim Golden [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html). Or perhaps more directly though [`fileapi`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32file.html).

Comment: Why not just use [os.path.getctime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT, CalledProcessError
cmd = 'wmic datafile where name="C:\\\\Users\\\\Public\\\\test.txt" get creationdate | findstr /brc:[0-9]'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print( "program output:", out.decode().rstrip())
```

`out.decode().rstrip()` returns a *string*, something like `'20210113222350.636280+060'`.

**Explanation**:

1. Escape all `\` (*Reverse Solidus*) in Windows path.
2. Check returned value type: `type(out)` ==> `<class 'bytes'>`; decode it to string.
3. Strip all trailing whitespaces using  the method `rstrip()`.

Note: `import os; os.path.getctime("C:\\Users\\Public\\test.txt")` returns a *float* value `1610573030.6362805` which is an epoch time format, imho (GMT `Wednesday, 13 January 2021 21:23:50.636`).